# Customize Ember View in route.render() call (or an alternative)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, view, ember.js, single-page-application

I'm trying to create a generic modal dialog view, that I can call from any controller in the app. I already have something like this working:

```js
App.ModalManaging = Ember.Mixin.create({
actions: {
    openModal: function (modalName, model, callback) {
        this.controllerFor(modalName)
            .set("model", model);
        this.set("modal", {
            callback: callback,
            name: modalName
        });
        this.render(modalName, {
            into: "application",
            outlet: "modal",
            controller: "application",
            view: "modal"
        });
    }
    //... other stuff
});
```

So, for each modal, I create a separate controller class and set the supplied object as its model. Then I use the `render()` method to render modal view/controller/template into 'modal' socket in the main layout. The way modal collects user actions and provides response to the calling controller is outside the scope of this question. Suffice to say, that part works.

Well this part works too, but I don't like it. Controller per modal seems like an overkill. All I need is a view with a few properties, which could communicate directly with Application route.

So for the last few hours, I've been trying to somehow customize the view object that is used by the `render()` method.

This doesn't work:

```js
this.render(modalName, {
    into: "application",
    outlet: "modal",
    controller: "application",
    view: new App.ModalView({
        message: "Are you sure?"
    })
});
```

I was going through the ember source and it seems there's nothing like this either:

```js
this.render(modalName, {
    into: "application",
    outlet: "modal",
    controller: "application",
    view: "modal",
    viewHash: {
        message: "Are you sure?"
    }
});
```

Basically, I need the programmatic equivalent of the `{{view}}` helper, including the ability to provide my own hash.

I suppose I could use a fixed ContainerView instead of the empty outlet and manipulate that, but that seems equality clunky as modal controllers.

Any ideas on how to achieve this or something similar would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Update: a way to do it using private `router._lookupActiveView()` method.

```js
var modalView = App.ModalView.create({
    templateName: modalName,
    message: "Are you sure?"
});
this.router._lookupActiveView("application")
    .connectOutlet("modal", modalView);
```

This seems to be working, but I'm not sure that using private method is any better than the clunky solutions with controller->model and ContainerView.

Still looking for that one solid, canonical solution.

Comment: I also asked an almost identical question on the ember discussion list here:

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/passing-view-options-with-ember-route-render/4650

Comment: @AndrewHacking thanks for the notice. I'll keep an eye on it.